# aligning text and buttons in flex div CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to align Text on the left and button controls on right in `display: flex` div.

```
<CustomFieldContainer>
  <StyledWellContainer>
    <FieldDetails key={id}>
      <H4 bold>{label}</H4>
      <StyledBody>({capitalizeFirst(type)}) {required && <StyledSpan>REQUIRED</StyledSpan>} </StyledBody>
    </FieldDetails>
    <DeleteAction {...props} />
  </StyledWellContainer>
</CustomFieldContainer>
```

this to what I got so far.

below is the CSS for all the above reactjs elements.

```
const CustomFieldContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;


const FieldDetails = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: none;
`;

const DeleteButton = styled(Button)`
  flex-basis:33.33%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left:auto;
  display:block;
`;
```

this makes

[image]

what I am trying to achieve is very simple, as below

[image]

any help would be tremendous, the basic idea is to main a container to have texts on the left and controls on the right. thank you.

Update:

```
const StyledWellContainer = styled(WellContainer)`
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 0;
`;


import styled from 'styled-components';

const WellContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: ${({ theme, borderType }) => (borderType === 'attention' ? theme.color.border.negative : theme.color.border.light)};
  border-radius: 12px;

  & > * {
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-bottom: ${({ theme, disableDivider }) => (disableDivider ? 'none' : theme.color.border.light)};
  }
  & > :last-child {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
`;

export default WellContainer;
```

Update after changes, advised by adam.

[image]

Comment: What are the styles for `StyledWellContainer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `StyledWellContainer` styles need changing such that:

```
  flex: 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
```

Currently it is a column, which is why the button appears below rather than by the side.

By adding row, this fixes that. `flex: 1 0` tells it to stretch to fit the parent, and `align-items: flex-start;` will prevent the content of the button being stretched to height.

You also need to let the button be its base size and not tell it to grow:

```
const DeleteButton = styled(Button)`
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
`;
```

Comment: that is being used globally.

Comment: Yes, add it to your `StyledWellContainer`

Comment: Or you mean, the component is being used elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have styled it on top of existing, details, I will update the image what it results too. you can check above question again, I am posting details

Comment: You could always use `!important` to override stuff. But I think im missing some info -- if you add it to the `StyledWellContainer` styles, it should take precedence. If it doesnt, use `!important`

Comment: Ah wait sorry I see the confusion. Sorry I edited after to say StyledWellContainer, which was my original intention, not WellContainer.

Comment: yes if you see above on update section, `const StyledWellContainer = styled(WellContainer)` StyledWell is using another WellContainer, which is being used globally but I have applied your change as well. which results in the above picture.

Comment: Ok cool, let me fix that give me a min

Comment: Cool, edited with additional change

Comment: Hi Thank you for that, it looks better but the issue is that the main `StyledWellContainer` have become very large now, https://imgur.com/o1945PS like this. We want to make not that much large as you can see in above demo picture. you know what i mean?

Comment: Yeh makes sense. You can edit the `flex-basis` on the `StyledWellContainer` to change this. So instead of `flex: 1 0;` you can do `flex: 1 0 50%;` for example.

Comment: Though its generally better to keep `flex: 1 0;` and then add a `max-width`. This will mean it still looks nice on mobile (cos 50% of a small phone screen is very small).

Comment: any idea why button has got squeezed this much? https://imgur.com/3ybBuNo

thank you for all the comments and answer,

Comment: I think likely it doesnt play nice as a flex-child -- hard to say without the button code. An easy solution to this would be to wrap the button in a new `<div>` called `ActionsWrapper` or something and move the `flex: 0 0 auto; margin-right: 0; margin-left: auto;`  to that new div. You'll need this anyway if you add more actions.

Comment: Okay thank you I did that. the only final question would be https://imgur.com/Ax8LXUh can we make its height less? it has way more height now its StyledWellContainer

Comment: Its the margin and padding on `& > * {`.

Comment: correct, Thank you, I have reached to max what I should be, but one last thing. https://imgur.com/sGjxwCU i have added an other button to ActionWrapper but its comes as this.

Comment: No worries :D. Ah you will need to add `display: flex; flex-direction: row` to the action wrapper

Answer (score 0):

`StyledWellContainer` needs to be the flex container, not `CustomFieldContainer`

```
const StyledWellContainer = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

const FieldDetails = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
`;

const DeleteButton = styled(Button)`
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left:auto;
  display:block;
`;
```

Comment: I have updated the `StyledWellContainer` as well please see above to more clarification